# Pyspark & HDFS: Add new dataframe column to existing parquet files in hdfs

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, parquet

let me first start with my scenario:
I have a huge dataframe stored in HDFS. I load the dataframe in a spark session
and create a new column without changing any of the existing content. After this, I want to store the dataframe to the original directory in HDFS.

Now, I know, I can practically do with with spark's write operation in the fashion `df.parquet.write("my_df_path", mode="overwrite")`. Since the data is immense, I'm investigating whether there is a so to speak column-wise append-mode or method, that does not write the complete dataframe back only the difference to the stored data. The final target is to save both memory and computational effort for the HDFS system.